# Django DeleteView not make delete

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I want to convert user deletion from FBV to CBV

> My FBV

```
def delete_student(request, pk):
student = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=pk)
student.delete()

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("students:get_students"))
```

> My CBV

```
class DeleteStudentView(DeleteView):
model = Student
form_class = StudentForm
template_name = "students/students_list.html"
success_url = reverse_lazy("students:get_students")
```

> student_list.html

```
 <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                   href="{% url 'students:delete_student' student.pk %}">Delete</a>
            </td>
```

There is no error, but no selection occurs. What could be the problem?

Comment: A `DeleteView` deletes with a POST or DELETE request. This is mandatory by the specs of the HTTP protocol. Your FBV is not HTTP compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DeleteView` deletes with a POST or DELETE request. This is mandatory by the specs of the HTTP protocol. Your FBV is not HTTP compliant.

You thus will need to make a mini-form to do this. For example make a hidden form with:

```
<td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_item({{ student.pk }});">Delete</button></td>

<!-- … -->

<form method="post" action="{% url 'students:delete_student' %}" id="delete_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="pk" id="delete_pk">
</form>

<script>
function delete_item(pk) {
    var hidden_item = document.getElementById("delete_pk");
    hidden_item.value = pk;
    var form = document.getElementById("delete_form");
    form.submit();
} 
</script>
```

In the `urls.py` we define an entry for the `StudentDeleteView` *without* parameters:

```
# students/urls.py

from django.urls import path

app_name = 'students'

urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('student/delete/', StudentDeleteView.as_view(), 'delete_student'),
    # …
]
```

In the `DeleteView`, you then determine the object with the primary key:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class DeleteStudentView(DeleteView):
    model = Student
    success_url = reverse_lazy('students:get_students')

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(Student, pk=self.request.POST.get('pk'))
```

To make your function-based view HTTP compliant, you should enforce that it can only do this with a POST or DELETE request, for example with a [**`@require_http_methods(…)`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods


@require_http_methods(["DELETE", "POST"])
def delete_student(request):
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=request.POST.get('pk'))
    student.delete()
    return redirect('students:get_students')
```

and thus use the same "trick" with the mini-form.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ça m'a beaucoup aidé.
I got an error due to the fact that in students/urls.py where you indicated , it was written:

path("delete/<int:pk>/", DeleteStudentView.as_view(), name="delete_student"),

After I removed <int:pk> everything worked.
And now if I want to use uuid instead of id, do I need to specify this directly in the views themselves, where is it necessary?

Comment: @Nikolay What is meant by `Merci beaucoup....`? please write in English.

Comment: @Nikolay: you will need to add string litrals to the `delete_item` call, so `delete_item('{{ student.pk }}')` in the `onclick="..."`.